# I want to have a live feed of my computers webcam on a website

Tags: php, html, flash

How could this be done? If it can't be done via webcam what should I use to put a live video feed on the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind getting your hands dirty you can use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to stream directly from your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ustream](http://www.ustream.tv/), you can set up your own channel and broadcast it live.